# Dynamically insert object into existing object

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a simple model, like this:

```
var person = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: "30"
}
```

But how would I go about inserting a new object into the existing one? Say I make a new object:

```
var pets = [{name: "Lucky", type: "Dog"}, {name: "Paws", type: "Cat"}];
```

I will need to dynamically generate various models and insert them into various sections of my model.

My final model would look like this:

```
var person = {
        name: "bob",
        age: "30",
        pets: [
            {name: "Lucky", type: "dog"},
            {name: "Paws", type: "Cat"}
        ]
    };
```

Comment: you can accept an answer by clicking the green outlined checkmark next to the answer you want to select

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but how I understand it, all you need to do is set a new attribute of `person`.

```
var person = {
        name: "Bob",
        age: "30"
    },
    pets = [{ name: "Lucky", type: "Dog" }, { name: "Paws", type: "Cat" }];

person.pets = pets;

console.log(person); // Object: (String) name, (String) age, (Array) pets;
```

You could also use EMCAScript 5's `Object.create()` method.

Answer (score 0):

create an array within person:

```
person.pets = [
   {name: "Lucky", type: "dog"},
   {name: "Paws", type: "Cat"}
];
```

or

```
var pets = [{name: "Lucky", type: "Dog"}, {name: "Paws", type: "Cat"}];
person.pets = pets;
```